# How To Handling Interface For Multi Inputs With Same Name React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I Used React With Typescript using React-Hook-Form

And I Try To Get Data From Multi Inputs with same name;

```
Interface {
    test: string[];
}

<form>
    <input name="test[0]" />
    <input name="test[1]" />
    <input name="test[2]" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
<form>
    {test?.map(item => {
      return <input name=`${item}` />
    })}
</form>
```